# UITextView editingrectforbounds

Tags: swift, uitextview, cgsize

There are anything like `editingrectforbounds` properties for `UITextView` ?!
I need to limit a text `CGsize`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is an [`NSTextContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/index.html). I recommend reading [the Apple Guide for Text Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/TextLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000158-SW1), it explains in detail how to do various types of text layouts and the Cocoa APIs involved. There's also an Apple Guide for  [Text Handling in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542)

```
var txtView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(), textContainer:NSTextContainer())
```

Or if it's an existing UITextView you can set a new text container.

```
txtView.textContainer = NSTextContainer(NSMakeSize(width, height))
```

Comment: I'm using that code to resize the `UITextedField`, I need the same for `UITextView` : `func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldString = textField.text as NSString
    let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString
    let stringSize = newString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:textField.font])
    return stringSize.width < textField.editingRectForBounds(textField.bounds).size.width
}`

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work for anyone. You'll want to update your question, not post code into a comment.